# Override the return key type of the UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, return-type

I am adding a `UIToolBar` with cancel and next buttons above the keyboard when I edit the `UITextField`. The next button should behave exactly like the `"next"= "returnkeytype"` of the `UITextField`.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: what do you mean by  `"next"= "returnkeytype" `? you need to pop the keypad on next click?

Comment: If I understood your question, you want to dismiss keyboard on return that is by clicking next button?

Comment: @MeeraJPai do the return key of keypad dismiss the keyboard, by default?

Comment: @MilKyWaY you have to set it to YES in the delegate method - textFieldShouldReturn and also connect the delegate

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem then you can use the delegate method of textField

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;// called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code on selector of your next button. Replace your textfield name with textfield.

```
- (IBAction)onNextClick:(id)sender
{
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```